# How can align items correctly using flexWrap in FlatList

Tags: react-native, flexbox

https://imge.to/i/6seRw

I want it to look like instagram explore page. When i tried flexWrap:'wrap' there is an aligment error. Next item doesn't go the right place.

```js
    _renderItem({ item }) {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity style={[{marginLeft:5,marginBottom:5},{width:item.width},{height:item.height}]} onPress={() => {console.log(item.key)}}>
                <Image style={[{width:item.width},{height:item.height}]} key={item.key} source={{uri:item.image}} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }

    render() {
        const itemData = [
            {key: 'A', width: 120, height: 120, image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/120.png'},
            {key: 'B', width: 120, height: 120, image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/120.png'}, 
            {key: 'C', width: 120, height: 120, image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/120.png'},
            {key: 'D', width: 120, height: 120, image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/120.png'},
            {key: 'E', width: 245, height: 245, image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/245.png'},
            {key: 'F', width: 120, height: 120, image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/120.png'},
            {key: 'G', width: 120, height: 120, image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/120.png'},
            {key: 'H', width: 120, height: 120, image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/120.png'},
            {key: 'I', width: 120, height: 120, image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/120.png'},
            {key: 'J', width: 120, height: 120, image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/120.png'},
            {key: 'K', width: 120, height: 120, image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/120.png'},
            {key: 'L', width: 120, height: 120, image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/120.png'},
            {key: 'M', width: 120, height: 120, image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/120.png'},
            {key: 'N', width: 120, height: 120, image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/120.png'},
            {key: 'O', width: 120, height: 120, image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/120.png'},
            {key: 'P', width: 120, height: 120, image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/120.png'},
            {key: 'R', width: 120, height: 120, image: 'https://via.placeholder.com/120.png'}
        ];

        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <FlatList
                    contentContainerStyle={{justifyContent: 'center',flexDirection:'row',flexWrap:'wrap'}}
                    data={itemData}
                    renderItem={this._renderItem}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case use can use `numColumns` and `columnWrapperStyle` props from FlastList.
Here's example:

```
<FlatList
  numColumns={2}
  columnWrapperStyle={styles.columnWrapper}
  keyExtractor={(val) => (`flat_list_item_${val.id}`)}
  horizontal={false}
  data={data}
  renderItem={this.renderCard}
/>
```

Comment: So are you trying to implement isotope layout?
In that case, why not using this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-masonry-list

Comment: I think it has also same problem since some of my items cover 2 columns.